# Read a file into an array using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file-io

I am currently reading a file and storing the data in an array named `@lines`. Then, I loop through this array using a `for` loop and inside the loop I match on certain values:

```
$find = "fever";

if ($_ =~ /$find/) {
    print "$_\n";
    $number++;
    #@lines =
    #print ("there are : " . $number);
}
```

At the moment, I am using a scalar, `$find`, with a value of `fever` instead of performing the repetitive statements for each filter.

Can I pass an array for comparison instead of a scalar keyword?

Answer (score 33):

If you read a file into a list it will take everything at once

```
@array = <$fh>;  # Reads all lines into array
```

Contrast this with reading into a scalar context

```
$singleLine = <$fh>;  # Reads just one line
```

Reading the whole file at once can be a problem, but you get the idea.

Then you can use `grep` to filter your array.

```
@filteredArray = grep /fever/, @array;
```

Then you can get the count of filtered lines using `scalar`, which forces scalar (that is, single value) context on the interpretation of the array, in this case returning a count.

```
print scalar @filteredArray;
```

Putting it all together...

```
C:\temp>cat test.pl
use strict; use warnings;  # always

my @a=<DATA>;  # Read all lines from __DATA__

my @f = grep /fever/, @a;  # Get just the fevered lines

print "Filtered lines = ", scalar @f;  # Print how many filtered lines we got

__DATA__
abc
fevered
frier
forever
111fever111
abc

C:\temp>test.pl
Filtered lines = 2
C:\temp>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it clarified how to get a filehandle for an arbitrary file, say if you have a filename in `$filename`. __DATA__ is a new one on me, by the way, but I've never been more than a casual Perl user.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Perl 5.10 or later, you can use smart matching (`~~`) :

```
my @patterns = (qr/foo/, qr/bar/);

if ($line ~~ @patterns) {
    print "matched\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Tie-File-0.96/lib/Tie/File.pm). It loads the file into an array, which you can manipulate using array operations. When you untie the file, its components will be saved back in the file.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/) module, which is convenient.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

my $fname = shift or die 'filename!';
my @lines = grep /fever/, read_file $fname; # grep with regular expression
print @lines;
```

If you're new to Perl, take a look at the `map` and `grep` operators, which are handy for processing lists.

Also, take a look at the [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) utility, which is a great replacement for `find`/`grep`. (Actually, it's a superior alternative.)