# From Python 2.7 to Perl 5, conversion

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-2.7

How different is Perl 5 compared to Python 2.7?

I've been trying out Perl 5, and it looks hard as I already had problems just trying to open/read/close a file earlier.

I have regex Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

SyslogText = open('syslog.txt', 'r')
OutputText = open('results.txt', 'w')
KeywordText = open('keyword.txt', 'r')

listOfKeywords = []

for keyword in KeywordText:
    listOfKeywords.append(keyword)

for string in SyslogText:
    for keyword in listOfKeywords:
        if keyword in string:

            hostName = re.search(r'\s[A-Z]+\s', string, re.I)

            dateAndTime = re.search(r'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}', string, re.I)

            moreResults = re.search(r'\:\s[^^]+\S', string, re.I|re.M)

            portInfo = re.search(r'[A-z]+[[]\d+[]]', string)

            if portInfo:

                   print '**' + keyword + '**' + ' ' + hostName.group(0) + dateAndTime.group(0) + moreResults.group(0) + ' ' + portInfo.group(0) + '\n'

                   OutputText.write('**' + keyword + '**' + ' ' + hostName.group(0) + dateAndTime.group(0) + moreResults.group(0) + ' ' + portInfo.group(0) + '\n')

            else:

                print ('**' + keyword + '**' + ' ' + hostName.group(0) + dateAndTime.group(0) + moreResults.group(0) + ' ' + keyword + '\n')

                OutputText.write('**' + keyword + '**' + ' ' + hostName.group(0) + dateAndTime.group(0) + moreResults.group(0) + ' ' + keyword + '\n')
```

Using this example, when converting to Perl, how does one write it in Perl, especially the `for` loop?

I have learned Perl from the website http://perldoc.perl.org/, but I didn't really understand everything too clearly on how the `for` loop should be written.

I have started converting it to Perl (part of it)

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $syslogFile = 'syslog';

open (my $info, '<', $syslogFile) or die "Could not open $syslogFile";

while (my $line = <$info>)
{
    chomp $line;
    print "$line\n";
}
```

I'm stuck on the `for` loop part as I am not too sure how to write it in Perl. Also, is calling `close` a requirement when opening and reading a text file? If so, when do you use it? I did read about it in perldoc, but I do not understand it.

Comment: Perl uses a C-style for loop, which has an initializer, condition, and step//incrementer, which is very different from Python. (Python has no initializer, condition, nor incrementer). It just iterates until `StopIteration` is raised on a sequence.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh You don't see that style very often in Perl code. The more popular construct would be the [foreach-style loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops).

Comment: Being as the Perl while() loop replaced the 2nd Python for() loop I'm leaving that one out.  The remaining (above and below) Python for() loops would best be done in Perl using [read entire file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948360/perl-read-a-file-into-an-array) and [Perl's map function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

Comment: **Warning: Do not use `[A-z]` in regexes.** It matches uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters as you expect, but it also matches several punctuation characters whose code points lie between `z` and `A`.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl equivalent to a Python loop of the form:

```
for X in Y:
```

where `Y` is an array, would be:

```
for my $X (@Y) {
    …
}
```

In the case where `Y` is a file, the `while` loop in your question is correct.

---

As far as your other question goes: closing files is not strictly required in Perl, just as it isn't in Python either. (The file will just stay open until the file handle goes out of scope — in this case, that happens when the process exits.)

Comment: If you use lexical file handles, as DBaculio does, files will be closed when their handle goes out of scope.